# Updating Overpass Data?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, josm

I have local Overpass server installed with some snapshot data.

Is there something like query data into graphical editor, edit the geometries and then update the Overpass server with the modified data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overpass API `update_database` process uses .osc (OSM Change format files) file format for updates.

To generate such a file based on your own edits, a number of steps would be needed:

1. Run your own instance of the OSM website (called rails port), which includes setting up an OSM database
2. Do some edits either via the built iD editor, Potlatch or maybe JOSM
3. Run another tool called `osmosis` to produce an .osc file based on the contents of your local OSM database or more specifically on changes since the last invocation of `osmosis`.

Once you have this .osc file, you're reading to update Overpass with it. On a real server, osmosis typically runs in 1 minute intervals to produce minutely diffs. Overpass API simply consumes those minutely diff osc files to update its local database.

That's all nothing for the faint-hearted, so expect quite some significant time to get this up and running. Each tool and app I mentioned has extensive documentation on its own both for installation, configuration, etc., which I'm not going to repeat here for obvious reasons.